# What is the best way to convert a normalized database into a single table form suitable for Stata

Tags: sql-server, stata, denormalization

I have a normalized database and a researcher needs to perform some analysis using Stata. It seems like I will need to write a script to generate a normalized table representing the fields of interest found in the database.

Are there tools that can help simplify this task, or, is it best to write a custom script to perform the de-normalization.

Comment: SSIS will be easy to handle this.

Comment: @TonyDong - SSIS sounds like overkill here. The OP simply wants to take some normalized structures and denormalize them for reporting. This is quite common.

Comment: Yes you will need to write the sql to denormalize your structures yourself. There are some automated tools that can help but I have found they can get you to a decent starting point at best. You almost always need to come back and tweak it to make it correct.

Comment: @TonyDong Thank you! Would SSIS be a tool to drill down also or is Stata better

Comment: SSIS is a tool which can run script / stored procedures, and it can include complexes logic. If you need update your de-normalization data very often, it is the way I suggested.

Comment: For what it's worth, many experienced researchers using Stata (or other statistical languages) would prefer to receive multiple tables and handle the data-related tasks themselves. I only mention this to point out that multiple tables are themselves suitable for Stata (in the sense of the question asked in the title of this topic), although perhaps not for the particular user the OP is working with.

Comment: @WilliamLisowski thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No you have to put all the fields in one table for the purpose of denormalization.  You have to put all the normalized table in to on.